# Add Read More Tag to a post content (Single.php)

Tags: posts, single, read-more

I have wordpress custom theme made from scratch including:

```
header.php, footer.php, single.php, index.php, functions.php
```

For Listing the blog list i used index.php with excerpt and read more link to the respective post.

index.php

```
if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts())  : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="single_excerpt">
        <h1 class="red_text"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read_more"><button class="btn btn-default" type="">Read More</button></a>
    </div>


<?php endwhile;
```

functions.php

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

This works fine as i expected, but the problem is with single.php as when i want to add read more tag to the post content after the first paragraph,nothing is happened. Please help me to add read more tag from backend to a post content after a first paragraph or as desired and then on single post view only the content will display which is before the tag and after that a read more button and after clicking the button full content will display on the same single view of post.

single.php

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">



    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts())  : the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="single_post">
                                <h1 class="red_text"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                <div class="post_info">
                                    Posted by: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> | Posted on: <?php the_date(); ?> | Posted in:<?php the_category(', '); ?> | <?php comments_popup_link('No Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
                                </div>

                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php else : ?>
                            <div class="post">
                                <h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', 'brightpage'); ?></h3>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>                         

                        </div>
```

Comment: `function.php`, not `functions.php` ? - https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File

Comment: Name your functions file `functions.php`. You have an empty value for the read more link, change that to `return 'something';`

Comment: Hi,Sorry i wrote that was by mistake actually that is not function , i have functions.php in my theme.

Comment: And the function above is working fine for read more link on the list of blogs using index.php

Comment: I need to add read more tag to the post content from the backend, And single post view is using single.php

Comment: Add read more tag to single.php ? I don't understand..

Comment: Read More tag using post editor inside the content of the post and single post use single.php to display the single post. Please help me to sort it out. Thanks

Comment: I also update my single.php in a question above.

Comment: The `single.php` template is for displaying the full content, unlike the index where you can show just an excerpt and link to the full article..

Comment: Yes samuel you are right, I only need to add read more tag from the editor to the post content after that when post is displayed, if post have read more tag in the content then the post will show only the part which is above the tag and after cliking the read tag full content will open to the down.